# Accessing Table Data from Sites Task List with Apps-Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Site which is an implementation of the Tasks, which gives me a table containing a few columns (Task, Assigned To, Status, Priority, Due Date, % Complete).

Example Data:

[image]

I'm trying to use App-Scripts to access the data in this list. Through the SitesApp interface I can get a list of items in the page but when I try and get the value of the list item it's only giving me the Task column, not Assigned To, Status, etc.

The code I've got is as follows, I'm at the stage where I'm able to get an array of the ListItems, but haven't determined if I'm able to access the other columns, or if there's a proper way to access the data in these columns.

```
  // Get the tasks from the page
  Logger.log("Getting all tasks in %s for %s site %s", pageName, appDomain, siteName);
  var page = SitesApp.getSite(appDomain, siteName).getChildByName(pageName)
  var listItems = page.getListItems();
  var columns = page.getColumns();
  Logger.log("Task list length is currently %s items long", listItems.length);


  for(var i in listItems)
  {
    Logger.log(listItems[i].getValueByIndex(i));
  }
```

The `listItems[i].getValueByIndex` is giving me seemingly arbitrary output - as I get the task name of the last entry, the owner of the second, and the status of the first.

Example Output:

[image]

At this point I'm pretty stumped on what's going on and how to access this data. Has anyone solved this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to finally find a solution to this issue. My problem was trying to iterate through the task list when I should have been doing a get value by name for the column. The code that actually behaved the way I wanted it to was this:

```
 // Get the tasks from the page
 Logger.log("Getting all tasks in %s for %s site %s", pageName, appDomain, siteName);
 var page = SitesApp.getSite(appDomain, siteName).getChildByName(pageName)
 var listItems = page.getListItems();
 var columns = page.getColumns();
 Logger.log("Task list length is currently %s items long", listItems.length);


 for(var i in listItems)
 { 
   for(var x in columns)
   {
    Logger.log(listItems[i].getValueByName(columns[x].getName())); 
   }
 }
```